# In the Armor novel by John Steakley, why was this character killed?

Tags: armor-book, john-steakley

There's a point in the story where "Everybody's Hero"

> Nathan Kent seemingly kills Felix,

but it is revealed later that actually, what Kent did was

> somehow pop open Felix's armor and rescue him by throwing him into a ship for his escape. Kent is killed after saving Felix.

The wikipedia article on this novel says it was the 'trigger-happy security' of the ship who killed him. Why were they trying to kill Kent and Felix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They weren't trying to kill both Kent and Felix.

Chapter 33 VIII:

> That wasn't what I meant. I said so. Holly helped. He asked about Kent.
>
> "Kent's dead," was the uncarefree reply.
>
> "I know that. He died on Banshee. But what I..."
>
> "He didn't die on Banshee. He died on the Terra."
>
> We looked at each other. I went this time. "Lew... Felix? Is it Felix?"
>
> He nodded. " Of course."
>
> "We thought Kent killed you."
>
> He frowned. "He saved me. They killed him."
>
> "Who?"
>
> "Fleet," he said in a dead voice and knelt down to fiddle with the suit.

And then later, Felix describes how Kent had stolen the ship from Allie:

> Felix nodded back. He took the cigarette out of his mouth and regarded it lovingly. Then he tossed it away.
>
> "Kent put me on the ship and sent me off, still in his armor the whole time. When they tried to find out what was going on, he blocked them." Felix stared, remembering. His voice was very quiet when next he spoke. "I saw what happened from the port. They cut him in half." He shrugged, almost violently. "But I was long gone by then. To here."

I believe the implication was that everyone knew Kent by his armor. When Fleet saw his armor with an unrecognized man beside it in a stolen ship, they gunned down Kent, the strange man who'd stolen the ship. I would not be surprised if they figured that "Kent", in the armor, would be safe from a crossfire, so they opened up fully.

Comment: Okay, so the reason they were attacked by Fleet troops was because Kent stole a ship. Why did he felt the need to steal a ship and have Felix escape in it?

Comment: @DavidMcDavidson:
It's a bit confusing since the only real witnesses are Kent and Felix, but I believe that it's implied that Allie and Masao were killed in friendly fire during the attempt to evacuate them when the Hive sprung up beside them, and Kent thought it was necessary to get Felix out of there before he was blamed for it.

Comment: But wasn't the Hammer, coming from the Hive and homing on the transit beacon, that killed Allie? I don't remember any mention of Fleet personnel firing at anything at that moment.

Comment: Nope. There's a brief bit where security starts going after Felix. Shortly thereafter, Kent knocks Felix out and his life-signs cease on his suit, leading his compatriots, analyzing the memory coils, to believe that Kent killed Felix when in actuality, Kent had merely yanked Felix out of the suit.

Comment: I see. I'll read that part again and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I've reread the part where Allie dies and Felix carries his body back to the ship through the transit beacon. Barely anything hints at Felix possibly being blamed by the death of the Masao, except for this line: `People pushed against him, shoving him back from the growing center of alarm and accusations.` Still, its not really convincing. Anyways, this looks like the best interpretation, so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have much time to review the contents of the book and the entire sequence was a bit confusing to me. I guess that does the question as to why Kent abducted Felix up in the air, a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

Kent saved Felix by shoving him on that ship. The reason Felix needed saving was that he was constantly being deployed back to Banshee because of a computer glitch. He was going to keep getting sent back no matter how many times he was the only survivor. The reason that Fleet gunned down Kent is a little more vague, but we can guess that it was Fleet security responding to the ship being stolen and "over-reacting".

Answer (score 0):

No no no.  Kent was expendable.  Fleet knew who Felix is, or rather was... The ruler of the richest planet in the known universe.  The planet's royalty wanted him, no, needed him back after his father died.  His brother "wasn't you".
Kent, in all his naivety, was unaware of this.  He was traumatized by Banshee.  He was Horrified by Felix, the anomaly.  He felt a heroic need to save Felix from that planet.  He was in the wrong place at the right time.